# Top N by Count of Dimension Tableau

Tags: bar-chart, tableau-api, top-n

I am a bit new to Tableau.

I have two columns: DATE and Car Model

I want to create bar graphs for the Top 5 (Count of Car Model) each individual year on the same sheet.

When I select the Top N filter, it selects the **overall** top 5 models and displays counts for each such model.

However, each year has a different Top 5. I want to be able to get the top for that particular year only.

Can anyone help me with it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This you can do through function `INDEX`.  Do these steps (I am replicating your problem on sample superstore as you haven't given any data)

- I built a view/viz with `order date` & `customer name` rows shelf and `sum(sales)` on columns shelf.
- create a calculated field named say `INDEX` with formula `INDEX()`
- drag this `INDEx` field to `DETAILS` on `Marks card`
- right click, `edit table calculation` and set the following options
  -- specific dimensions (check both fields drag to adjust date field prior to second nested field)
  -- At the level (select second field name - customer name in my case)
  -- restarting at every (select first date field , order date in my case)
  -- sort order - CUSTOM - select Sales(Measure) with descending and aggregation as your measure (sum in my case).  A screenshot is attached for reference

[image]

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + drag INDEX field to Filter and select `1 to 5`.
- Your desired view is ready

[image]